# How do I detect when a UICollectionViewCell is created for the first time?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am using a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) to display cells in a grid. I would like to add a swipe gesture to each cell to trigger a shortcut for deleting the cell. If I were using [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead, it would have been easy. In [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), I would have dequeued a cell. If and only if the cell was nil, I would have attached a swipe gesture to a newly created cell. This process is not easy with UICollectionView.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UserCollectionViewCell* cell = [self.avatarCollectionView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:AVATAR_CELL_ID 
        forIndexPath:indexPath
    ];
    cell.user = [self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

There is no way to detect whether the cell is being created for the first time, because the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:) says:

> Your implementation of this method is responsible for creating,
>   configuring, and returning the appropriate cell for the given item.
>   You do this by calling the
>   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: method of the
>   collection view and passing the reuse identifier that corresponds to
>   the cell type you want. That method **always returns a valid cell**
>   object.

I can't just add the swipe gesture every time in this function because multiple gestures would be stacked up. I need to only add the swipe gesture only to a newly created cell.

[image]

Comment: Create a custom class of CollectionViewCell that has a property swipeGestureRecognizer. When the cell is dequeued ask if the property is nil and if it is init the recognizer and have the cell.swipeGestureRecognizer point to it.

Comment: Hm, forgot to add the recognizer to the cell.contentView after doing the init.                                              `[cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer]; cell.swipeGestureRecognizer = swipeRecognizer;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the gesture recognizer in the init method of your custom UICollectionViewCell which in this case might be UserCollectionViewCell.

Then you could implement custom delegate protocols and assign the view controller with the collection view as the delegate for your UserCollectionViewCell.

Or you could use NSNotificationCenter to handle the methods to and from the collectionview cell with the view controller.